# Search in databank for Integer with Like Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, jpql

I want to search for an Integer in a MySQL database with like. I am using `jdk-12.0.2` with `Hibernate`

If it would not be an Integer I can use this code:

```java
:what = "Help"
(ArrayList<Number>) entityManager.createQuery("FROM Number WHERE definition LIKE :what", Number.class ).setParameter("what", what + "%").getResultList();
```

This works perfectly and gives me my ArrayList of Numbers.

If I just use an SQL script I can use this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM juna where CAST(id as CHAR) like '1%';
```

But if I use `CAST(id as CHAR)` to replace the `definition` it gives me this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: Could not resolve requested type for CAST : CHAR
```

Can anyone help me on how to solve this problem?
(Suggestions to improve my working code are also welcome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cast` is not a part of jpql, that you're using when you're invoking `EntityManager#createQuery`. You should use `EntityManager#createNativeQuery` instead to use plain sql. See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery-java.lang.String-).